# New python NameError when trying to print csv file

Tags: python, export-to-csv, nameerror

My code previously worked to print to the csv file but recently started to produce a NameError. I have looked at lots of other similar questions but cannot figure out how to fix it. I am relatively new to Python.

```
data = glob.glob('filename****')
filenames = data

for filename in filenames:
  root = lxml.etree.parse(filename)
  for stitle in root.xpath("//fileDesc/titleStmt/title[1]"):
      stitle = stitle.xpath("string()")

  for ltitle in root.xpath("//fileDesc/titleStmt/title[2]"):
      ltitle = ltitle.xpath("string()")

  for date in root.xpath("//fileDesc/sourceDesc/bibl/msDesc/additional/adminInfo/note"):
      date = date.xpath("string()")

  for location in root.xpath("//fileDesc/sourceDesc/bibl/pubPlace"):
      location = location.xpath("string()")

  with open('file.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
      writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
      writer.writerow([filename, stitle, ltitle, date, location])
```

The specific error I am receiving is "NameError: name 'date' is not defined". I have used this code before and it worked. Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

I'm guessing you are running the program for the first time with values such that
`root.xpath("//fileDesc/sourceDesc/bibl/msDesc/additional/adminInfo/note")` is empty.

In such cases the name `date` is never bound, and hence when you try and execute the final statement

```
writer.writerow([filename, stitle, ltitle, date, location])
```

you see a NameError. This interactive session will demonstrate:

```
>>> for date in []:
...   pass
...
>>> date
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'date' is not defined
```

Comment: I changed the root.xpath and it worked! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are facing.
Since 7 is not gt 9 --> a is not defined.
In your case a 'date' was not found.

```
if 7 > 9:
    a = 11
print(a)
```

output

```
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```